# How to set a textarea content on my etherpad?

Tags: etherpad

I have a problem, I have upgraded my etherpad-lite and now, my etherpad can't read the source text.

Yesterday, if I'm userA and I'm first editor on pageA, I can see on etherpad editor a text on pageA (text get on textarea),
else,
I'm userB and I'm not first editor on PageA, i see the etherpad text with the userA's modifications.

I just see the defaultText setted in settings :/

How to solve the problem please?

Regards
Sebastien.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your Javascript console on UserB's browser, you should get some errors.